# How to decompile .class and jar file using Storyyeller/Krakatau

Tags: java, python-2.7, decompiler

I am trying to decompile a file using Storyyeller/Krakatau decompiler. I have already downloaded the relevant file and placed it inside a folder. I tried decompile the file using below syntax using command prompt.

=== Decompilation ===

**Usage:**

```
python Krakatau\decompile.py [-nauto] [-path PATH] [-out OUT] [-r] [-skip]
target
```

**PATH:** An optional list of directories, jars, or zipfiles to search for
    classes in. Krakatau will attempt to automatically detect and add the
    jar containing core language classes, but you can disable this with
    the `-nauto` option. For multiple jars, you can either pass a semicolon
    seperated list of jars or pass the `-path` option multiple times.

**OUT:** Directory name where source files are to be written. Defaults to the
    current directory. If the name ends in .zip or .jar, the output will be a
    zip file instead.

**-r:** Decompiles all .class files found in the directory target (recursively)

**-skip:** Continue upon errors. If an error occurs while decompiling a specific
    method, the trace back will be printed as comments in the source file. If the
    error occurs while decompiling at the class level, no source file will be
    emitted and an error message will be printed to the console.

**target:** Class name or jar name to decompile. If a jar is specified, all
    classes in the jar will be decompiled. If `-r` is specified, this should
    be a directory.

But I always get errors.I don't understand the above syntax.

Please explain this syntax

```
python Krakatau\decompile.py [-nauto] [-path PATH] [-out OUT] [-r] [-skip]
target
```

using a simple example.

Comment: download decompiler using this url                                    https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest and normal way to decompile with Krakatau is to decompile a jar.

Say you have a jar file named `Luyten.jar` in the current directory and you want to decompile every class in the jar and output it to the directory `temp`. Then you'd do something like

```
pypy -O Krakatau\decompile.py -skip -out temp Luyten.jar
```

Depending on whether you have JDK installed and where, you may need to explicitly pass the location of the jre in the path argument. For example

```
pypy -O Krakatau\decompile.py -skip -out temp -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar" Luyten.jar
```

If you want to decompile a specific class within the jar, you can add the jar to the path and specify the classname. If you need to specify a path to rt.jar as in the previous example, you can pass the `-path` argument multiple times or a single time separated by semicolons. For example to decompile only the class com.beust.jcommander.FuzzyMap$IKey,

```
pypy -O Krakatau\decompile.py -skip -out temp -path Luyten.jar com.beust.jcommander.FuzzyMap$IKey
```

You can also decompile classfiles that are outside of a jar, but it's a lot more annoying, because you have to make sure the directory layout is correct. You need to specify the directory that is the root relative to where the classes will be found.

For example, suppose you have a classfile located at ./Foo/Bar/com/beust/jcommander/FuzzyMap$IKey.class

```
pypy -O Krakatau\decompile.py -skip -out temp -path Foo/Bar com.beust.jcommander.FuzzyMap$IKey
```

In this case, the directory has to match the fully qualified classname exactly. A common mistake is to try to decompile with the wrong root directory. The nice thing about jars is that having the correct directory structure is automatic.

Comment: thanks for your solution and  thanks you for spending your  valueble time Antimony.

Comment: this decompiler is not good one.it doenst produce correct output

Comment: @NirangaSandaruwan What's the problem? Lack of resugaring? For unobfuscated code, you'd probably be happier with Procyon, but if you're trying to decompile obfuscated code, Krakatau's by far the best.

Comment: problem is some methods dont get decompiled properly.but Procyon do.other thing is some methods that dont get decompiled well with Procyon get decompiled with Krakatau.Im happy about that.but decompiled code has many break,while,label statements.so sometime its hard to undestand the code.if they can be resolve further.this is valueble decompiler.

Comment: Well I do work on improving it some times, but the thing is that the output has to be at least as complex as the input. So if the code you're trying to decompile is already complex, there's not much you can do in that regard.